# Select menus in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, select, model, relationship

I have the following code in my Rails 3 application, it's supposed to be displaying a select box with each `asset_type` record:

**assets_helper**

```
def asset_type_all_select_options
  asset_type.all.map{ |asset_type| [asset_type.name, asset_type.id] }
end
```

**_form.html.erb (Asset)**

```
<%= f.select :asset_type_id, asset_type_all_select_options, :class => "input-text", :prompt => '--Select-----' %>
```

and here are my models:

**asset.rb**

```
belongs_to :asset_type
```

**asset_type.rb**

```
has_many :assets
```

Using the above code I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `asset_type' for #<#<Class:0x007f87a9f7bdf8>:0x007f87a9f77d48>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Will this method not work with double barrel model names? Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `asset_type` in your assets_helper file is not defined. You would need to pass it in to the helper method

```
def asset_type_all_select_options(asset_type)
  # ...
end
```

Or use an instance variable that you define in the controller (e.g. `@asset_type`).

However, you can simplify this by using the `#collection_select` form helper.

**_form.html.erb (Asset)**

```
<%= f.collection_select :asset_type_id, AssetType.all, :id, :name, { prompt: '--Select-----' }, class: 'input-text' %>
```

Take a look at the API for [#collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) for details.